# Laravel 9 csrf token not working in postman 10.3

Tags: laravel, postman, csrf-token

I have a problem with implementing csrf token in postman. I puted script and added enviroment. That is what I found on internet, but it is no working, why?

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the error that I got.
[image]

Comment: why not try adding the csrf token in body as `_token`? I am not sure about postman's cookies. Maybe check the cookies part of postman if it has value?

Comment: same error, it doesn't help

Comment: which part of the code did not help?

Comment: the token in body or cookies?